# Blank screen due to React client side re-renders DOM with server side rendering implemented

Tags: reactjs, server-side, client-side, rerender

#### Background

I'm working on a react based (MERN.io) project( [Eve's Temptation](https://www.evestemptation.com) ). This project's stacks are mainly React, Redux, Webpack, Node and Express. After my implementation of server-side rendering. I found that, with no good network connection, a user can see a full-screen blank after some rendering finishes, then it re-renders. So it probably should be a re-render issue. I tested on MERN.io and add an extra div in server-side rendered string

From:

```
<div id="root">${html}</div>
```

To:

```
<div id="root"><div>${html}</div></div>
```

This can solve the

> warning.js?8a56:33 Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a 
>   container but the checksum was invalid. This generally means that you 
>   are using server rendering and the markup generated on the server was 
>   not what the client was expecting. React injected new markup to 
>   compensate which works but you have lost many of the benefits of server  > rendering. Instead, figure out why the markup being generated is
>   different on the client or server:

```
(client) <!-- react-empty: 1 -
(server) <div data-reactroot="
```

#### Although I used this method to solve the issue above, the white screen ( client re-rendering ) issue occurs.

[image]
[image]

Here I use code from `https://github.com/Hashnode/mern-starter` as an example, which is our project based on.

#### Client index.js:

```
/**
 * Client entry point
 */
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
import App from './App';
import { configureStore } from './store';

// Initialize store
const store = configureStore(window.__INITIAL_STATE__);
const mountApp = document.getElementById('root');

render(
  <AppContainer>
    <App store={store} />
  </AppContainer>,
  mountApp
);

// For hot reloading of react components
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./App', () => {
    // If you use Webpack 2 in ES modules mode, you can
    // use <App /> here rather than require() a <NextApp />.
    const NextApp = require('./App').default; // eslint-disable-line 
global-require
    render(
      <AppContainer>
        <NextApp store={store} />
      </AppContainer>,
      mountApp
    );
  });
}
```

#### Server: server.js

please see it on `https://github.com/Hashnode/mern-starter`

### ======= HERE ARE HOW TO REPRODUCE THE ISSUE: =======

#### Step 1:

Turn off the minification on production mode so that we can read the js code in browser and target the critical code:

comment the UglifyJSPlugin in webpack.config.prod.js ( line 80~85):

```
  new ChunkManifestPlugin({
    filename: "chunk-manifest.json",
    manifestVariable: "webpackManifest",
  }),
  // new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
  //   compressor: {
  //     warnings: false,
  //   }
  // }),
],
```

#### Step 2:

Run mongodb and in the project folder run `npm run bs` to run product mode

#### Step 3:

In Chrome browser resources, we can see js file like `app.cb4f935522b22f1d48a0.js`, we can find the code near line 10316

```
// Initialize store
    var store = (0, _store.configureStore)(window.__INITIAL_STATE__);
    var mountApp = document.getElementById('root');

    (0, _reactDom.render)(_jsx(_reactHotLoader.AppContainer, {}, void 0, _jsx(_App2.default, {
      store: store
    })), mountApp);
```

#### Step 4:

Set a breakpoint on `(0, _reactDom.render)...`, before running this function, client-side already rendered some content with a server-side rendered document, after stepping over this function, the screen will be blank white.

[image]
[image]

I'm trying to find a solution to avoid this rerendering but It's kind of difficult for me,

Comment: Hi Evan have you succeed since to avoid the blank?